# Linker options for Boost

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm wondering if there are any simple ways to link boost libraries (all or individual) via some entry like....

```
-lSDL_ttf
```

The above links SDL's True Type Font library. Can this be done with boost? If so, I'm not sure what file I'm linking for to link. I'm currently using boost_1_40_0.

If this isn't possible, or there are better ways to do this, I'd be happy to hear them.

P.S. I'm using the CodeBlocks IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most boost libraries don't need to be linked as they are header only.

For those that are not header only, see the instructions [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) on the naming conventions and make sure you put the folder containing the boost libraries in your library search path if you want to avoid specifying it explicitly.

Comment: Well, I'm getting an error regarding an undefined reference to boost::system::get_system_category(). What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: You probably missed linking to boost.system - something like `-lboost_system-*foo*`

Comment: Ah thanks. Now getting error regarding undefined reference to WinMain@16. Haven't searched it yet though so I'll do that first.

Comment: I had to link to both. I'm reading that the WinMain@16 error occurs when you've created the wrong kind of project. It's current type is a GUI application, but that is what it is supposed to be ( I recently switched OS's, so I'm having to set things up again. I should probably write it down this time. ) I'm unsure what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 7, A few updates to this post:

a. Following installation instructions the following link, I placed the zipped file in /usr/local, resulting in an installation directory of:

```
/usr/local/boost_1_60_0
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

b. As stated on the above page, many of the Boost libraries are "header only." In other words, there is no library, and you don't have to link the libraries; there is nothing to link! If you try and link them, you will get an error! You just have to specify the header location, like so:

[image]

Of course, if you're using a Boost library that must be compiled, you may have to link it differently, but it's important to keep this in mind.

c. Be sure to check the permissions on the installation directory. I installed as root, and had to do a chmod 755 on the install, as show below. If permission are not set, you will get the generic and utterly unhelpful "library not found" error.

[image]